# Zero of Electric Potential Energy

Tags: electrostatics, potential, conventions

When you have a positive charge and a negative charge, the line that cuts perpendicularly between their separation distance is an equipotential line of 0 volts. The math indicates that at that point, $V=\frac{kQ}{r}+\frac{k(-Q)}{r}=0$. But do these formulae not presume the zero of electric potential to be when $r=\infty$, that is, $V=\frac{kQ}{\infty}=0$? Why are there two zeroes, or which one is the real one?

Comment: I believe that in your formula for $V$ you should have two different $r$s, i.e $V = \frac{KQ}{r_1} - \frac{kQ}{r_2}$, unless your two charges are on top of each other

Comment: @BySymmetry Not necessarily. The formula for V doesn't involve any vectors, so in the original setup, $r_1=r_2=r$ is possible without them being in the same location. The positive charge is on one side, distance $r$ away and the negative is on the other side, distance $r$ away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the zeroes are "real" to answer the question.

There is absolutely no problem with multiple points in a space having the same electric potential.

Note that we have ASSUMED the potential to be zero at infinity and based upon that assumption we have found out the potential to be again zero at the equidistant point between two opposite charges. So there is no contradiction at all with two points having the same (zero) potential.

And please understand the fact that such absolute values of potential are not something we are bothered about; what we tend to rather be interested in is the potential difference between two points.